# BDR Replication issue

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-bdr

I am trying to setup 2-node BDR replication and i am getting the following error while running bdr_init_copy.

> /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/bdr_init_copy -d "host=10.10.145.111
>   dbname=apimgtdb port=5432" -U postgres
>   --local-dbname="host=10.10.145.110 dbname=apimgtdb port=5432" -n nodeawswest -D  /postgres/pgsql-9.4/data

```
< 2015-06-05 14:56:55.846 PDT >LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2015-06-05 14:49:09 PDT
< 2015-06-05 14:56:55.951 PDT >LOG:  entering standby mode
< 2015-06-05 14:56:55.951 PDT >LOG:  starting up replication identifier with ckpt at 9/F5000060
< 2015-06-05 14:56:55.956 PDT >LOG:  redo starts at 9/F5000060
< 2015-06-05 14:56:55.972 PDT >LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 9/F5000128
< 2015-06-05 14:56:55.972 PDT >LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
< 2015-06-05 14:56:55.977 PDT >LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 9/F6000000 on timeline 1
< 2015-06-05 14:56:56.639 PDT >LOG:  recovery stopping at restore point "bdr_6157013497737678047", time 2015-06-05 14:56:57.137408-07
< 2015-06-05 14:56:56.640 PDT >LOG:  recovery has paused
< 2015-06-05 14:56:56.640 PDT >HINT:  Execute pg_xlog_replay_resume() to continue.
< 2015-06-05 14:56:56.821 PDT >ERROR:  cannot execute DELETE in a read-only transaction
< 2015-06-05 14:56:56.821 PDT >STATEMENT:  DELETE FROM pg_catalog.pg_shseclabel WHERE provider = 'bdr';
< 2015-06-05 14:56:56.837 PDT >LOG:  received smart shutdown request
< 2015-06-05 14:56:56.838 PDT >FATAL:  terminating walreceiver process due to administrator command
< 2015-06-05 14:56:56.840 PDT >LOG:  shutting down
< 2015-06-05 14:56:58.169 PDT >LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Comment: Here are the steps that i have executed on 2-node

Comment: mv /postgres/pgsql-9.4/data /postgres/pgsql-9.4/data_old
mkdir /postgres/pgsql-9.4/data

/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_basebackup -h 10.10.145.111 -p 5432 -X stream -U postgres -D /postgres/pgsql-9.4/data


cp /postgres/pgsql-9.4/data_old/postgresql.conf /postgres/pgsql-9.4/data
cp /postgres/pgsql-9.4/data_old/pg_hba.conf /postgres/pgsql-9.4/data
chmod -R 700 /postgres/pgsql-9.4/data

/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/bdr_init_copy -d "host=10.10.145.111 dbname=apimgtdb port=5432" -U postgres --local-dbname="host=10.10.145.110 dbname=apimgtdb port=5432" -n nodeawswest -D  /postgres/pgsql-9.4/data

Comment: What's the exact BDR version? If you're not sure, `SELECT bdr.bdr_version()`.

Comment: X-posted to http://stackoverflow.com/q/30676846/398670

Comment: Your steps are illegible, please put them in an edit to the question instead.